# Android Progress Dialog directly goes to 100% while uploading file

Tags: android, file-upload, server, progressdialog

I am trying to upload file to server. file sucessfully uploaded but my problem is progress dialog directly goes 0 to 100% or(0-50%-100%). It does not show according to file upload. please tell what should be edited in this code...

```
public class ShowStudent extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private TextView messageText;
private Button uploadButton, btnselectfile;
private int serverResponseCode = 0;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
private String upLoadServerUri = null;
private String filePath=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_student);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    btnselectfile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectfile);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    upLoadServerUri = "http://onsitesupport.info/diary/uploadproject.php";
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},100);
            return;
        }
    }
    enable_button();
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == 100 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
        enable_button();
    }else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},100);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (arg0==uploadButton) {
        dialog =new ProgressDialog(ShowStudent.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.show();
        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                uploadFile(filePath);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
public  void enable_button(){
    btnselectfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new MaterialFilePicker()
                    .withActivity(ShowStudent.this)
                    .withRequestCode(10)
                    .withFilterDirectories(true)
                    .start();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        File f  = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH));
        filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
      //  String mimeType= URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(f.getName());
        messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +filePath);
    }
}
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+filePath);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+filePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int sentBytes=0;
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                sentBytes += bufferSize;
                dialog.setProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100/bytesAvailable));
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
           // Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    } // End else block
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is because the stream returned by `conn.getOutputStream()` is internally buffered. As result when you are sending small files your dialog doesn't show progress of writing to network but rather to that internal buffer. To ensure you can add

```
dos.flush();
```

after each write operation in your loop. It should block until data will be written to network. Of course such hack will degrade overall upload performance. There are at least two alternatives:

- Find another way to obtain number of bytes that were indeed written to network
- Perform `flush()` not so often, e.g. say after writing of some sane amount of data (e.g. few kB)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
dialog.setProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100/bytesAvailable));
```

from background thread. In order to update UI you have to call this method from UI thread.

Comment: does not worked bro. tried in runOnUiThread.. still same issue